# How can I incorporate Python scripts into web pages?

Tags: python

I'm interested in having Python scripts in a web page. I'm planning simple scripts on the order of splitting strings and maybe a little bit more.

As in Javascript...

```
<html>
<script>
  //stuff goes here
</script>
</html>
```

Except I want to use Python in the exact same way, or at least in a remotely similar way. Is there any way to accomplish this without a framework?

If I need a framework in the end, which one is best?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Flask is a convenient and lightweight framework for web development in Python: http://flask.pocoo.org/ . I suspect that Django might be a bit heavyweight for what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Short answer: No, it's not (easily) possible. JavaScript is a client-side scripting language, Python is server-side. You'll have to employ a different programming model, and pass data forth and back between the frontend and backend. And you're likely to still need JS on the frontend, even if parts of it are dynamically generated by the Python backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**...Generally, you can't include a python script in `<script></script>` tags.

Why not? Python isn't one of the scripting languages built into the visitors' browsers, like Javascript, or commonly installed as a plug-in like Java or Flash.  There may very well be a Python plug-in somewhere, but it is not in common use.  Asking someone to install a plug in, even Java or Flash, to view your site is considered a hassle and security risk by many.

The usual way to run python for web page generation is server-side, but you are not asking about that, so how could it run browser-side?  The answer is the python interpreter must be written in an available browser language like Javascript or Java.

And surprise!, there is a Python interpreter written in Javascript ([Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/))!  Since this runs Python in Javascript, it does not require any plugin and would be visible to most visitors.  You will need the skulpt code and probably can't use `<script>` tags but could locate the python code in an visitor-editable `<textarea>` input according to the skulpt instructions.

There is a more well-known variant of Python one written in Java ([Jython applet example](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/applets/converter.html)) but your visitors would need to have the Java browser plugin installed for it to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

using Python Scripts in web without framework is a very tedious task. You can do this with **Templates**

See the docs here:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#templates

Answer (score -2):

**CGI**  : This will include Python scripts in a web page.

The Common Gateway Interface is used to exchange data between the web server and a custom script. You can refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm to get more information.

If you are going to use web framework then I will suggest Django.

You will get more info in below link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Can I know why you voted down? Is cgi not used in webpage?. If you don't know then go through the link which I given.

Comment: No one actually uses CGI with Python. If anything, you'd use [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). But more to the point, this doesn't do what the OP asked (client side scripting), since it doesn't *"include Python scripts in a web page"* - it's all server side.